# Choose restart policy for my services in the docker-compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-container

I´m having troube selecting the restart policy for my Services.

My Application needs two Containers to run.

- Tomcat Container with deployed .war file
- Postgre Container with Postgre Database

My Questions:

Does anyone have Experience with choosing the restart policy?

Do I need to have the same restart Policy for both of my services?

I would straight forward choose the *on-failure* policy. When something crashes in the container it should immediately startup back again.

Offical Docker Documentation: [https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/#:~:text=Restart%20policy%20details,-Keep%20the%20following&text=A%20restart%20policy%20only%20takes,going%20into%20a%20restart%20loop](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/#:%7E:text=Restart%20policy%20details,-Keep%20the%20following&text=A%20restart%20policy%20only%20takes,going%20into%20a%20restart%20loop).

Comment: What trouble are you actually having?  You tagged this with "docker-compose"; Compose has equivalents to most of the `docker run` options, including a [`restart:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#restart) setting.

Comment: I´m having no trouble, I´m just wondering if there is a best practice for the restart policy, based on what is running inside the container. Maybe when running a database inside a container the "always" restart policy is the best e.g, that is what I want to find out with this question.

Answer (score 1):

We have tried **on-failure** and that based on particular needs for some projects and services.

I think all depends on your needs. Have you consider what are your needs? Some questions here:

1. Do you need the linked containers are start in the correct order?

> Restart policies ensure that linked containers are started in the correct order.

2. Are you planning to use a process manager to start containers?

> Docker recommends that you use restart policies, and avoid using process managers to start containers.

3. Have you try to experiment with all the policies and determine the policy that covers what you project needs?

> - on-failure[:max-retries]
> - always
> - unless-stopped

Comment: We want to use the docker restart policys. These Two Container are linked, so it would be nice if the linked container also restarts if the others fails. When the Max Retries is reached, the container does not automatically startup again. We Monitor our Nodes where the Containers are running. If we set the max retries to e.g 10 we would easily see if something is wrong when the container cannot startup for ten times. I thougt there are Best practices for restart Policy when applying to an Tomcat Container or Postgres Container.